# Eclipse error: unable to get workspace root / No class Definition Found

Tags: eclipse

**Problem description:**
In a work space I have a number of packages and every package has a number of class files. Almost every class file has main method defined in it. Previously, whichever file I wanted to run I used to open that and run. But now, doesn't matter which file I open and try to run, it always runs a file say "X" from my workspace. If I remove that file it throws an exception saying "NoClassDefinitionFoundError". I also get the error saying: unable to get workspace root.

It had been working fine for me until I started getting this error. Specifically, how does eclipse load a class to run? May be something has been messed in there.

PS: These class files are not logically related. They are individual files with main method to solve some small problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be a silly mistake but here is the actual cause which I found today when I hit the same issue again:

The class that I was trying to run had a "private" main method because of of which it was picking up the main method of previous class which I had run on eclipse.

I'm not sure how it picked up or how these things are managed in eclipse but yes this is what caused me the error and it got rectified after changing the main method to public.